# the loop printing post in one grid

Tags: loop

I am trying to print my wordpress post into 2/2 grid but I think my div's are messed up.

```
    <div class="grid-container">
            <?php
                if($query->have_posts()):
                        while($query->have_posts()):
                                $query->the_post();
                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):
                                    echo '<div class="grid">'
            ?>

                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium_large');
                                endif;
                ?>
                    <h1 class="page-sub-main-header" style="color: #00adee;">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php the_title() ?>
                                </a>
                        </h1> 
                                <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
                                <div class="footer-meta">
                                    <a href="$query->the_permalink()"><?php the_category(); ?> </a>
                                    <span> <?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <?php endwhile;  ?>
                <?php endif;
                echo '</div>';
                ?>
        </div><!--grid container-->
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the closing div after endif and Move it inside endwhile and the `<div class="grid">` should be outside the post thumbnal check

Comment: thanks. it is always confusing. how to make sense of it so I don't do this again?

Comment: You should have a basic understanding of layout if you can't get it then practice wireframing and flowcharts and give yourself a visual idea of the flow and view